# HttpWebRequest with JWT authentication always responds with 401 unauthorized

Tags: .net, authentication, jwt, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-401

I'm developing a webservice in ASP.NET Core 3.1 that uses JWT authentication and authorization for security. I've been testing it using Postman and Javascript (axios), and everything seems to work great.
But now I have to update a .NET 4.6.2 application to access this webservice, but somehow it always responds with statuscode 401 'unauthorized', and I just don't get why.

The simplest version of the client is shown below:

```
            var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(@"http://localhost:49767/Information/TestAuthentication");
            request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwcm9kdWN0IjpbIjBuR29nVU40amtLd1pVb0xiK2pvMUE9PSIsIjZ0dmFWMHpWU0VLZk1GMDhqL2diRUE9PSJdLCJzdWIiOiJhMWQxNDI2OC1iZmMzLTRiM2EtOGNkNS04NDUyNzhjNWNiMzciLCJleHAiOjE1ODMzMTgwMTcsImlzcyI6IlRlc3QuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiVGVzdC5jb20ifQ.132BrlZidEUDEBIGK_nNr7Dw50pFyTl15jMGuRwbsts");

            request.Method = "GET";


            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                throw new Exception(response.StatusDescription);
```

When I try the exact same simplistic call from Postman, it responds with a clean status200 code.

[image: postman version]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

In Postman, you are sending a regular header key value pair with key value Authorization with the value being a Bearer token. However, in your code, you are sending it through as an Authorization header.

Try to send it through as a regular header with the key value pair like this: 
`request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwcm9kdWN0IjpbIjBuR29nVU40amtLd1pVb0xiK2pvMUE9PSIsIjZ0dmFWMHpWU0VLZk1GMDhqL2diRUE9PSJdLCJzdWIiOiJhMWQxNDI2OC1iZmMzLTRiM2EtOGNkNS04NDUyNzhjNWNiMzciLCJleHAiOjE1ODMzMTgwMTcsImlzcyI6IlRlc3QuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiVGVzdC5jb20ifQ.132BrlZidEUDEBIGK_nNr7Dw50pFyTl15jMGuRwbsts");`

If youd like to send through the Authorization header, you may also try 
`request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwcm9kdWN0IjpbIjBuR29nVU40amtLd1pVb0xiK2pvMUE9PSIsIjZ0dmFWMHpWU0VLZk1GMDhqL2diRUE9PSJdLCJzdWIiOiJhMWQxNDI2OC1iZmMzLTRiM2EtOGNkNS04NDUyNzhjNWNiMzciLCJleHAiOjE1ODMzMTgwMTcsImlzcyI6IlRlc3QuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiVGVzdC5jb20ifQ.132BrlZidEUDEBIGK_nNr7Dw50pFyTl15jMGuRwbsts";`

Comment: This isn't it... i found that my problem seems to go away when I disable HTTPS redirect on the server. This isn't a solution to the problem, but I've got some new ideas now.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, so the problem is caused by the servercode
`app.UseHttpsRedirection();`

Apparently the https redirect clears the 'authorization' header

I can get a functioning application by using the uri from a simple anonymous request.

```
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(@"http://localhost:49767/Information");
var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

var uri = new Uri(response.ResponseUri, "/Information/TestAuthentication");
request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
```

But it feels weird to me that this was so difficult to find!